# Change form style in Bootstrap for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a code snippet which exactly is whatever I need, with a little change. [The sample code is here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/input-validation-colorful-input-groups), and I tried to create a sample form which can be accessed [here](http://58.69.62.110/test/).
The only adjustment I need is, I want to show asterisk for mandatory fields once the form loaded. But as of now, it shows an error style (which is not desired when the page opens). How can I change the form?

Script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-group input[required], .input-group textarea[required], .input-group select[required]').on('keyup change', function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form'),
            $group = $(this).closest('.input-group'),
            $addon = $group.find('.input-group-addon'),
            $icon = $addon.find('span'),
            state = false;

        if (!$group.data('validate')) {
            state = $(this).val() ? true : false;
        } else if ($group.data('validate') == "email") {
            state = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test($(this).val())
        } else if ($group.data('validate') == 'phone') {
            state = /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/.test($(this).val())
        } else if ($group.data('validate') == "length") {
            state = $(this).val().length >= $group.data('length') ? true : false;
        } else if ($group.data('validate') == "number") {
            state = !isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) && isFinite($(this).val());
        }

        if (state) {
            $addon.removeClass('danger');
            $addon.addClass('success');
            $icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
        } else {
            $addon.removeClass('success');
            $addon.addClass('danger');
            $icon.attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
        }

        if ($form.find('.input-group-addon.danger').length == 0) {
            $form.find('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $form.find('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    $('.input-group input[required], .input-group textarea[required], .input-group select[required]').trigger('change');
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <h2>Input Validation + Colorful Input Groups</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
         <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-text">Validate Text</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-text" id="validate-text" placeholder="Validate Text" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-optional">Optional</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-optional" id="validate-optional" placeholder="Optional">
                  <span class="input-group-addon info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-optional">Already Validated!</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-text" id="validate-text" placeholder="Validate Text" value="Validated!" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-email">Validate Email</label>
               <div class="input-group" data-validate="email">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-email" id="validate-email" placeholder="Validate Email" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-phone">Validate Phone</label>
               <div class="input-group" data-validate="phone">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-phone" id="validate-phone" placeholder="(814) 555-1234" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-length">Minimum Length</label>
               <div class="input-group" data-validate="length" data-length="5">
                  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-length" id="validate-length" placeholder="Validate Length" required></textarea>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-select">Validate Select</label>
               <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="form-control" name="validate-select" id="validate-select" placeholder="Validate Select" required>
                     <option value="">Select an item</option>
                     <option value="item_1">Item 1</option>
                     <option value="item_2">Item 2</option>
                     <option value="item_3">Item 3</option>
                  </select>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="validate-number">Validate Number</label>
               <div class="input-group" data-validate="number">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="validate-number" id="validate-number" placeholder="Validate Number" required>
                  <span class="input-group-addon danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" disabled>Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to show asterisk in blue instead of cross in red?

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment following line from your script.

```
$('.input-group input[required], .input-group textarea[required], .input-group select[required]').trigger('change');
```

This is last line in your `document.ready`. This is the line responsible triggering change event on page load and changing asterisk to cross. Just comment this line and you are good to go.

**EDIT**
Add `danger`class instead of `info` class; this will show your asterisk in red by default and on validation it will get green background with a check mark. I.e modify your asterisk form-group as following.
            
                Optional

**NOTE**
Undo script changes I suggested before.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have another question. Right now, asterisk is in a blue background, and after entering the correct info, it shows a check mark again in blue background. How can I change the background of the check mark to green after receiving the correct information?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your requirement. If this is what you need then please mark this as accepted answer as well.

Comment: Thank you again, it works awesome!

I have one more question. I am going to use this form for signing up new users, so for some of the fields it needs to double check with the server in order to make sure this username was not already taken. To do that, I think using Ajax
Can you please tell me, how can I test a value in the above code with the server? In case of a repetitive username, I'd like to show a cross in red background (and maybe a text indicating this username is already in use).

Comment: OK, I am afraid the previous solution still has an issue. Right now, if I start typing in any of the boxes, it will activate submit button. But I want to make it active only once "all" of the mandatory fields provided correctly. How can I do that?

Comment: I have made requested changes.

Comment: Thank you Zeshan. I updated the code based on your recommendation. But still the background does not change to green, and submit button never activate. Can you help?
Try it here: http://158.69.62.110/test/